# How can I incorporate a variable into a string?

Tags: templating, string, variable, concatenation

How can I incorporate a variable into a string, so that the result is a longer string that includes the contents of a given variable?

For example, I have a variable called `apple` and its value is "Arlington Pippin" (it's a [type of apple](http://www.orangepippin.com/apples/arlington-pippin)). I'd like to end up with a phrase that reads:

> There is an Arlington Pippin.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Yep, I like apples.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you‘ve got a multi-lingual site (or even if you don’t), you can pass variables into strings with the [`|t` filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#translate-or-t):

```
{{ "Welcome back, {name}"|t( {'name': currentUser.name} ) }}
```

(See http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations for details on how you can use the `|t` filter to translate your text.)

Answer (score 18):

I know three ways:

- **Using `format()` (look for [type specifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php))**

  ```
   {% set string = "There is an %s."|format("apple") %}
  ```
- **Using string interpolation (assuming that `apple="apple"`)**

  ```
   {% set string = "There is an #{apple}." %}
  ```
- **Using string concatenation (assuming that `apple="apple"`)**

  ```
   {% set string = "There is an " ~ apple %}
  ```

Comment: i recommend string interpolation become the informal standard IMHO.