# Accessing and Manipulating a Variable

Tags: templating, attribute, concatenation

Hopefully simple variable / concatenation question: What is the best way to retrieve the url of a specific asset the name of which should be concatenated from an asset field variable and a text string?

I need to end accessing the url of an asset like so – {{asset.**portrait**ThumbSmall.url}}, but I am in a loop where “**portrait**” could also be “**landscape**” ...or “**square**”, and is derived from an asset field variable on an asset called “thumbnailCrop”. With me so far?

So something like...

```
    {{asset.thumbnailCrop ~ "ThumbSmall" ~ .url}}
```

…only, unlike this, it should actually work.

I did read this -> [How can I incorporate a variable into a string?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/200/how-can-i-incorporate-a-variable-into-a-string) …but I’m trying to incorporate a string into a variable. Not sure it applies.

Someone in the Slack channel suggested...

```
    {% set thumbnail = attribute(asset, thumbnailCrop ~ "ThumbSmall") %}
    {{ thumbnail.url }}
```

But it doesn't work, and I was also wondering if it wasn't possible to make something more compact.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
{% set transform = (asset.thumbnailCrop.value ?: "portrait") ~ "ThumbSmall" %}
{{ asset.url(transform) }}
```

If `asset.thumbnailCrop` is a dropdown field (or similar), you'll need to specifically extract the **value** from it. If no value is found, it'll fall back to using the "portrait" string.

Comment: YOU DID IT :-) Thank you. Earlier suggestions were very similar, just missed ".value". Working great now.